# When using scrollTop() my page creates an extra blank div. How do i get rid of it? My code is below

Tags: jquery, html, css

When you click on 'What it this place?' The jQuery will show() the div below and scroll down to it, however when clicking on 'Continue' on that next page, it not only scrolls down to the third div but also creates a blank div above it. How do I fix that?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#about1').hide();
  $('.question').click(function(){
    $("#about1").show();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#about1").offset().top}, 500);
   
  });
  $('.question2').click(function(){
    $("#about2").show();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#about2").offset().top}, 500);
   
  });
  $('#about3').hide();
  $('.question3').click(function(){
    $("#about3").show();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#about3").offset().top}, 500);
   
  });
  $('#about4').hide();
  $('.question4').click(function(){
    $("#about4").show();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#about4").offset().top}, 500);
   
  });

  /* Push the body and the nav over by 285px over */
  $('.icon-menu').click(function() {
    $('.menu').animate({
      left: "0px"
    }, 250);

    $('body').animate({
      left: "285px"
    }, 250);

  
  });

  /* Then push them back */
  $('.icon-close').click(function() {
    $('.menu').animate({
      left: "-285px"
    }, 250);

    $('body').animate({
      left: "0px"
    }, 250);

  });


});
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
/* Initial body */

 body {
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

/* Initial menu */
.menu {
  background: #FDF3E7 repeat left top;
  left: -285px;  /* start off behind the scenes */
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 285px;
  top: 0;
}

/* Basic styling */

.front {
  background-color: #8a0027;
background-image: url(http://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/45-degree-fabric-light.png);
/* This is mostly intended for prototyping; please download the pattern and re-host for production environments. Thank you! */
  height: 100%;
}

.menu ul {
  border-top: 1px solid #636366;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}

.menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #636366;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

.menu a {
  color:  #444;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.icon-close {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.icon-menu {
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.icon-menu i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.head_text{
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.head_text h1{
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: font-family: 'Alice', serif;
  font-size: 9em;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #fff, 1px 1px 1px #000;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.head_text p{
  font-family: Gill Sans, Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;

  margin-top: 35px;
}
.head_text a{
  text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 300;
        color: #ffcc66;
}
.head_text a:hover{
  color: #FF9009;
}
.head_text a:active{
  color: #E44424;
}
button{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  padding: 15px 45px;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: "Bitter",serif;
  line-height: 1.8;
  appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 150px;
}
button:focus {
  outline: none
}
section.flat button {
  background: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);

  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: -1px 1px #417cb8;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}
section.flat button:hover,
section.flat button:focus,
 section.flat button:active {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
#about1 {
  background: #FFffff;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;

}
#about2 {
  background: #FFffff;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;

}
#about3 {
  background: #FFffff;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;

}
#about4 {
  background: #FFffff;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;

}
#about1 h2{
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Audiowide', cursive;
}
.text-about {
  text-align: center;
}
.text-about p{
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 90px;
  padding: 60px;
  max-width: 600px;
  font-size: 2em;
}
#about2 p{
  margin:  auto;
  margin-top: 1200px;
  padding: 60px;
  max-width: 600px;
  font-size: 2em;
}
#about3 p{
  margin:  auto;
  margin-top: 1200px;
  padding: 60px;
  max-width: 600px;
  font-size: 2em;
}
#about4 p{
  margin:  auto;
  margin-top: 1200px;
  padding: 60px;
  max-width: 600px;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400;300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='main.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alice' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- Google Analytics -->  
  <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-66102823-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

  </script>
  <!-- End Google Analytics -->

  <title>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-MJ8TK9"
    height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-MJ8TK9');</script>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

  <div class="menu">
    <!-- Menu icon -->
    <div class="icon-close">
      <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/uber/close.png">
    </div>

    <!-- Menu -->
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
    
    <!--Main Body-->
  <div class="front">
      
    <div class="icon-menu">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        Menu
    </div>
    <div class="head_text">
      <h1>Loveygram</h1>
      <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEX</p>
      <section class="flat">
        <button>Enter</button>
      </section>
        
      <a class="question" href="#">What is this place?</a>
    </div> 
  </div>

  <!-- About Page -->
  

    <div id="about1">
      <h2>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</h2>
      <p class="subhead">TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
      <div class="text-about">
        <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</br> </br>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
          <a class="question2" href="#">Continue</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="about2" >
        <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT. </br> </br> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
        <a class="question3" href="#">Continue</a>
    </div>

    <div id="about3" >
        <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
        <a class="question4" href="#">Continue</a>
    </div>

    <div id="about4" >
        <p>TTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
    </div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="love.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have forgotten to add $('#about2').hide(); for the second function of $(document).ready().

Answer (score 0):

Adding height to body should fix this & here is the snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#about1').hide();
  $('.question').click(function(){
    $("#about1").show();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#about1").offset().top}, 500);
   
  });
  $('.question2').click(function(){
    $("#about2").show();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#about2").offset().top}, 500);
   
  });
  $('#about3').hide();
  $('.question3').click(function(){
    $("#about3").show();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#about3").offset().top}, 500);
   
  });
  $('#about4').hide();
  $('.question4').click(function(){
    $("#about4").show();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#about4").offset().top}, 500);
   
  });

  /* Push the body and the nav over by 285px over */
  $('.icon-menu').click(function() {
    $('.menu').animate({
      left: "0px"
    }, 250);

    $('body').animate({
      left: "285px"
    }, 250);

  
  });

  /* Then push them back */
  $('.icon-close').click(function() {
    $('.menu').animate({
      left: "-285px"
    }, 250);

    $('body').animate({
      left: "0px"
    }, 250);

  });


});
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
/* Initial body */

 body {
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
   height:100vh;
}

/* Initial menu */
.menu {
  background: #FDF3E7 repeat left top;
  left: -285px;  /* start off behind the scenes */
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 285px;
  top: 0;
}

/* Basic styling */

.front {
  background-color: #8a0027;
background-image: url(http://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/45-degree-fabric-light.png);
/* This is mostly intended for prototyping; please download the pattern and re-host for production environments. Thank you! */
  height: 100%;
}

.menu ul {
  border-top: 1px solid #636366;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}

.menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #636366;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

.menu a {
  color:  #444;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.icon-close {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.icon-menu {
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.icon-menu i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.head_text{
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.head_text h1{
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: font-family: 'Alice', serif;
  font-size: 9em;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #fff, 1px 1px 1px #000;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.head_text p{
  font-family: Gill Sans, Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;

  margin-top: 35px;
}
.head_text a{
  text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 300;
        color: #ffcc66;
}
.head_text a:hover{
  color: #FF9009;
}
.head_text a:active{
  color: #E44424;
}
button{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  padding: 15px 45px;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: "Bitter",serif;
  line-height: 1.8;
  appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 150px;
}
button:focus {
  outline: none
}
section.flat button {
  background: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);

  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: -1px 1px #417cb8;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}
section.flat button:hover,
section.flat button:focus,
 section.flat button:active {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
#about1 {
  background: #FFffff;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;

}
#about2 {
  background: #FFffff;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;

}
#about3 {
  background: #FFffff;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;

}
#about4 {
  background: #FFffff;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;

}
#about1 h2{
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Audiowide', cursive;
}
.text-about {
  text-align: center;
}
.text-about p{
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 90px;
  padding: 60px;
  max-width: 600px;
  font-size: 2em;
}
#about2 p{
  margin:  auto;
  margin-top: 1200px;
  padding: 60px;
  max-width: 600px;
  font-size: 2em;
}
#about3 p{
  margin:  auto;
  margin-top: 1200px;
  padding: 60px;
  max-width: 600px;
  font-size: 2em;
}
#about4 p{
  margin:  auto;
  margin-top: 1200px;
  padding: 60px;
  max-width: 600px;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400;300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='main.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alice' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- Google Analytics -->  
  <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-66102823-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

  </script>
  <!-- End Google Analytics -->

  <title>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-MJ8TK9"
    height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-MJ8TK9');</script>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

  <div class="menu">
    <!-- Menu icon -->
    <div class="icon-close">
      <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/uber/close.png">
    </div>

    <!-- Menu -->
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
    
    <!--Main Body-->
  <div class="front">
      
    <div class="icon-menu">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        Menu
    </div>
    <div class="head_text">
      <h1>Loveygram</h1>
      <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEX</p>
      <section class="flat">
        <button>Enter</button>
      </section>
        
      <a class="question" href="#">What is this place?</a>
    </div> 
  </div>

  <!-- About Page -->
  

    <div id="about1">
      <h2>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</h2>
      <p class="subhead">TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
      <div class="text-about">
        <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</br> </br>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
          <a class="question2" href="#">Continue</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="about2" >
        <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT. </br> </br> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
        <a class="question3" href="#">Continue</a>
    </div>

    <div id="about3" >
        <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
        <a class="question4" href="#">Continue</a>
    </div>

    <div id="about4" >
        <p>TTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
    </div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="love.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) but unfortunately there's still all this extra white space when you scroll back up.

Comment: Is there a way to change the jQuery code instead to make the above divs hide after revealing the next one?

Comment: Did you click on "Full Page" ? I cant see any white space in the snippet above.

Comment: Yes, first of all full page, then click on 'What is this place?' that works fine, the body scrolls down and doesn't create an extra div, the click on 'Continue' and it also scrolls down but also creates this extra space.

Comment: I got your point, the slidings are completely controlled by user. Do have a look at [FullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) Hope this library can make what exactly you want

Comment: That's a very beautiful library! Thank you, I'll take queues from there. I tried to vote your answer UP but it doesn't let me cos I'm not experienced enough, sorry.